# In $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, let $I=\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$. Find the inverse of $2x+3+I$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, let $I$ be the ideal generated by $x^2+x+2$, $I=\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$. Find the inverse of $2x+3+I$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

I don't understand what $2x+3+I$ means. Is it just $2x+3+I=2x+3+x^2+x+2$?

If so, I can work from there. If not, any help/hints would be most welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $2x+3+I$ is the coset of $2x+3$ modulo the ideal $I$. In other words it is the set of polynomials $p(x)\in\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$ such that when $p(x)$ is divided by $x^2+x+2$ the remainder is equal to $2x+3$. Very much like the coset $\overline{2}\in\Bbb{Z}_5$ is the set of integer that have remainder $2$ when divided by $5$.

Comment: So just like the inverse of $\overline{2}\in\Bbb{Z}_5$ is the coset of an integer $a$ such that $2a\equiv1\pmod5$, here the inverse is the coset of a polynomial $a(x)$ such that $$(2x+3)a(x)\equiv1\pmod{x^2+x+2}.$$ Hint: Calculate the gcd of $2x+3$ and $x^2+x+2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]$ with Euclid's algorithm (you should get $1$), and use the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

What they mean is find the inverse of $\overline{2x+3}\in \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\langle x^{2}+x+2\rangle$. This amounts to finding an element $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, such that $g(x)(2x+3)\langle x^{2}+x+2\rangle$

Comment: Your last sentence is non-sensical. I can guess what you meant though :-)